# Ubuntu 14.0.4 freezes when I set up dual monitors

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I recently installed 14.0.4 on a new system and I've noticed that my computer will freeze at least 5 times in a work day, where I can move the mouse around, but i can't actually click on anything.  My keyboard works in the sense that I can get to a command prompt... but I'm not savvy enough to know which process to kill etc.

In any case, I've been testing over the past 2 weeks and I feel comfortable in saying that so far, it looks like the issue is related to having dual monitors set up. 
To test this theory, I removed the dual monitor set up ... since then I haven't had the system crash / freeze at all.

Both monitors are the same - 24 inch Samsung Sync Masters.  I'm not so savvy with hardware so I'm not sure where to start.  But my graphics card does come with outputs for two monitors.  I've googled how to look up information about my graphics card and here's what I've found:

```
me@mydev:~$  sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
[sudo] password for me: 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550] [1002:954f] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:02a8]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fe620000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fe600000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

me@mydev:~$ 


me@mydev:~$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550] [1002:954F]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] [1002]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe620000-fe62ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe600000-fe61ffff
me@mydev:~$
```

Any suggestions on how I can further troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: The same problem came to me when I used Alt+Tab for switching screens. It made me to go back to 12.04 since it has LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to 14.10 and all my problems went away.

Comment: What about those of us who cannot upgrade to 14.10?